# The proportional editing seems to be mirrored in some way?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices, mirror

I'm trying to move the vertices of the left leg of my character all around the armature (created by the **Manuel Bastioni LAB**) with the **proportional editing tool**,but when I press on **G** and then **X**,also the vertices of the right leg are moving. I thought that the **X mirror** option was enabled,but it isn't. So,why it happens ?

[image: error]

Instead,I have opened an old version of the same project and here you can see that it works as I want...

[image: ok]

Comment: Use the mouse wheel to increase or decrease the range of the proportional editing (the white ring). In your first picture the range is too high, therefore it also affects the other leg.

Comment: Is the Proportional Editing type the same for both files? Or one of them has Connected type?

Comment: thanks,Carlo. I've just learnt something that I didn't know : the difference between the connected and the enable option on the proportional editing tool.